# How can I collapse columns of a dataframe if there are NAs?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I want to remove the NAs in the following data frame so that I'm left with 3 columns instead of 4. The names of the columns don't matter.

```
structure(list(Practical1 = c("65", "85", NA, "60", NA), Practical2 = c("55", 
"75", "100", NA, "35"), Practical3 = c(45.45, 50, 86.36, 40, 
72.73), Practical4 = c(NA, NA, "92", "79", "71")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

I'd get something that looks like this:

```
pracA, pracB, pracC
65, 55, 45.45,
85, 75, 50,
100, 86.36, 92,
60, 40, 79,
35, 72.73, 71
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, with `na.omit`:

```r
dat <- as.data.frame(t(apply(dat, 1, na.omit)))
colnames(dat) <- paste0("prac", 1:3)
```

output

```r
  prac1 prac2 prac3
1    65    55 45.45
2    85    75 50.00
3   100 86.36    92
4    60 40.00    79
5    35 72.73    71
```

In `tidyr` with `unite` + `separate`:

```r
library(tidyr)
unite(dat, "a", starts_with("Practical"), na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  separate(a, into = str_c("prac", 1:3), sep = "_")
```